# How to send data from another thread to QOpenGLWidget object in GUI thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, qtopengl

I have a GUI thread where the QOpenGLWidget object is created. I use another thread to process data and generate RGBA values for an image.

I cannot call the QOpenGLWidget object in the data processing thread.

How can I send data from the data processing thread to the QOpenGLWidget object?

(The data processing thread is created using boost, so I cannot use `moveToThread()` which requires QThread)

Comment: you can send a signal across threads (remember to use Qt::QueuedConnection) and pass the data as a parameter

Comment: Check my answer for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882718/errors-whan-using-qtimer-in-a-multithreading-application/71972431#71972431.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use QThread and signal slot for "realtime" data communication, it is leaky.
You should use SafeQueue architecture like this:
https://codetrips.com/2020/07/26/modern-c-writing-a-thread-safe-queue/

And remember to handle queue size to avoid overflow.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer makes no sense.  What's 'leaky' about signals/slots?  Why use `SafeQueue` and how is it really any different from using `Qt`'s own thread-safe queue -- the event queue?