# errors whan using QTimer in a multithreading application

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I am starting a api rest server in a separate Qthread in my application.

the server shall use  a library which is using Q timer in several places.

The compilation is ok. But i have errors in execution. I obtained the following errors in several places:

```
QThread::start: Failed to create thread (Code d’accès non valide.)

QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

I can't move Qtimers in the server thread. I need to keep the library code sourse as it is.

is there a solution to face this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your library stuff is located in thread `A`, and your server is located in thread `B`, and you want to use your library from server's code.

For this, you'll have to create a separate class `C` (derived from `QObject`), which you need to put in thread `A`. Its purpose then would be to make the whole communication between the library and the server.

This communication should be asynchronous (e.g. via slots/signals). It can also be synchronous (thread `B` waits `C`'s slot to finish), but it's a bit more complicated and probably not recommended.